# How to make apprequest with custom text, like MyCalendar?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests, facebook-ui

How to make this request ?
(i mean custom text)

[image: request]

Answer (score -1):

Romka,

Use the message: field. e.g.

FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'You should learn more about the Platform.'
  });

From http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/apprequests

Comment: For _invites_, the message does not get displayed in the notification (only in app center) – at least for “normal” apps. Facebook only displays the message part of the request right there for some of the “big players”, that operate under special conditions.

Comment: Correct, I misunderstood the question.